# Adding button programmatically swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, addtarget

I am trying to add button programmatically, I created button, it shows in app, but problem that when I write `.addTarget` in `#selector` occurs error (it builds successfully, but action do not work) I tried to write `playAction()` and `playAction(sender:)` and `playAction`. None of them work. [image]

```
playPauseButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

@objc
func playAction(sender: UIButton){
    print("Hello")
}
```

UPD: I solved by creating just system button and changed it. Maybe my Xcode have bug and because of that occurs error.

Comment: so ... you cant see Hello ?

Comment: Show how you setup and adding your button

Comment: This syntax is fine. Given how you defined your function, the `#selector(playAction(sender:))` syntax is correct. The problem rests elsewhere (e.g. with breakpoint/log statement, make sure you’re even hitting this `addTarget` line; use view debugger to confirm that the button has “user interaction” enabled and that there’s not something in front of this button that might be consuming the touches; etc.).

Comment: Also, I might suggest stepping away from your current project. Make a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by creating a blank project and adding the bare essentials to manifest the problem. Often when preparing a MCVE, you’ll often figure out the source of the problem yourself. And if not, you’ll have a minimal project that you can upload, that we can look at.

Comment: Is the button the only thing in your `UIView`? Is it possible there is another view overlapping this one or its interaction is disabled? Check the Debug view hierarchy just to be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change with

```
playPauseButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playAction), for: .touchUpInside)
```

this is ok:

```
@objc
func playAction(sender: UIButton) {
      print("Hello")
}
```

works for me

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs to have the `@objc` attribute. This allows it to be looked-up as a selector.

```swift
@objc
func playAction(sender: UIButton) {
      print("Hello")
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, nothing wrong with what you've shown then. Sorry I couldn't help!